# ERROR Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component

Tags: react-native, react-hooks, use-effect

ERROR Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

Comment: Post the code which cause the issue.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1: **How To Solve Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in React-hooks Error?**
To Solve Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in React-hooks Error Here is The easiest solution is to use a local variable that keeps track of whether the component is mounted or not.

2: **Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in React-hooks**
To Solve Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component in React-hooks Error Here is The easiest solution is to use a local variable that keeps track of whether the component is mounted or not.

**SOLUTION 1:**
I built this hook that works just like React’s useState, but will only setState if the component is mounted. I find it more elegant because you don’t have to mess around with an isMounted variable in your component!

`const [count, setCount] = useState(0);`

**SOLUTION 2**
Here is The easiest solution is to use a local variable that keeps track of whether the component is mounted or not. For Example.

```
function Example() {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("waiting...");

  React.useEffect(() => {
    let isCancelled = false;

    simulateSlowNetworkRequest().then(() => {
      if (!isCancelled) {
        setText("done!");
      }
    });

    return () => {
      isCancelled = true;
    };
  }, []);

  return <h2>{text}</h2>;
}
```